Ufw output doesn't seem right
Is there any possible way that this command:
sudo ufw status numbered
would output:
enabled
because I can't think of any reason it would, but it did.

It just means there are no rules set in place, and that default rules will apply, which are whatever is reported by sudo ufw status verbose. If you were to set a rule, it would display, along with its id.

So the default rules aren't set rules that can be numbered?

No, defaults apply to all incoming / outgoing or routed traffic that doesn't match a specific rule, and the traffic can be allowed, denied or rejected; there must be a default behavior set for each type of traffic, and the default behavior can be changed using sudo ufw default allow|deny|reject [incoming|outgoing|routed]; it makes little sense to number these default "rules", I wouldn't even call them "rules", they just define how the firewall should behave when no rule matches.
